# How to resize image to a fixed height and width without losing aspect ratio in winjs?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have an image area in my application with width:530px and height:510px. I want to place images in that area but the images comes in different different sizes. how to crop or scale the image without losing aspect ratio to fill that area. Is there any native methods available in winjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options for that.

One is to use the [ViewBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229771.aspx) that WinJS provides you. The ViewBox can only have a single child (so you would have your  tag as its only child perhaps or a div that contains your img) and it will scale that child (using CSS transforms) up to fit into its container (without changing the aspect ratio). It's pretty slick.

Another option is to set the image as the CSS background-image property of a container (such as a div) and set the background-size property to `contain`. This will stretch the image up to the size of the container.

A final option that you have to resort to if your case is a bit special is not such a bad option after all. In the `updateLayout` method of your page, you can refer to the  element and explicitly set its CSS properties to fit. At that point you'll know all about the layout and can easily do the math to figure out what size image should be. Here's some code from one of my projects where I do this. Notice that I'm comparing the aspect ratio of the screen and the image to determine whether I should size to the width or the height. Unlike your situation (I'm guessing), my code makes sure the image fills the screen and excess is clipped. I'm guessing you want your img to be contained.

```
function setImagePosition() {
    var img = q(".viewCamera #viewport img");
    if (outerWidth/outerHeight > img.naturalWidth/img.naturalHeight) {
        img.style.width = format("{0}px", outerWidth);
        img.style.height = "";
        img.style.top = format("{0}px", (outerHeight - img.clientHeight) / 2);
        img.style.left = "0px";
    } else {
        img.style.width = "";
        img.style.height = format("{0}px", outerHeight);
        img.style.top = "0px";
        img.style.left = format("{0}px", (outerWidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks setting image as a div worked well. These properties worked for me 

.item-img{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to scaling HTML images? If so, you can set either one, width or height. Whichever you set, the other will scale and keep image aspect ratio.